# How to define WIX agent requirement in TeamCity?

Tags: msbuild, wix, teamcity

I have add a WIX installer project to solution in Visual Studio 2013. The project is built with every commit on TeamCity. There are several build agents connected to TeamCity cloud, but only some have WIX installed.

Usually I would add the build agent requirement, so only the computer with WIX installed is selected for automated build.

What requirement should I select? Is there some environment variable I could use after WIX is installed?

I know I can set the environment variable manually on every computer I install WIX, but this is not nice solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a system environment variable called 'WIX', which holds the path WiX Toolset is installed to. It is created during WiX Toolset installation.

However, there might be a better way that avoids setting up any build agent requirements. Take a look at this article that explains [how to integrate WiX into daily builds](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/daily_builds.html). Basically, it suggests committing the required binaries along with the source code of your app.

Both approaches have pros and cons, it's your choice.

The agent need to be restarted after installing WIX. Then there will be

```
env.WIX
```

requirment in the Teamcity.